# Синхронизация проектов Eclipse через git

Tags: java, git, eclipse

Как лучше синхронизировать проекты Eclipse между разными машинами на разных ОС?

Принципы работы git ясны, репозиторий имеется, однако есть некоторые сложности:

1. Проекты эклипса на разных ос конфигурируются по-разному. Поэтому все служебные файлы приходится заносить в gitignore, так велит gitignore.io
2. Импортировать проект эклипса без служебных файлов на другой машине уже не получается. Импортируется обычный проект, без buildpath и прочих плюшек. Конвертировать его в java проект невозможно.

Каким образом можно наладить систему, чтобы на каждой машине был проект?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решение из англоязычного раздела.

- Импортируйте, как обычный проект
- Обратите внимание, что импортируемые данные не являются проектом Eclipse (нет build path)
- Откройте/создайте`.project` файл в папке импортированного проекта.
- Перейдите во раздел `source`
- > Найдите `<natures></natures>` и измените на `<natures><nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature></natures>` и сохраните файл
- Правый клик в Eclipse на папке `src`, перейдите в `Build Path...` и кликните `Use as Source Folder`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32407205/5244594

Для большего теоретического удобства в будущем стал работать с проектом maven, а не с проектом Eclipse. Больше универсальности и переносимости. При импорте проекта maven следует импортировать, как Existing Maven Project. Eclipse сам определяет, что проект принадлежит git.

В итоге мы имеем проект с автоматическим контролем зависимостей, находящийся в git-репозитории, что позволяет синхронизировать проект не только между машинами, но и между различными IDE, поддерживающими maven.

Comment: Поддерживаю, maven – отличное решение для java-проекта. Его и в контроль версий можно, и разные OC и IDE поддерживает.